# Trigger lambda on forgotPassword with Cognito

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, passwords, amazon-cognito, amazon-ses

I am trying to trigger a self made lambda which uses SES to send an email to the user if they forgot their password. The only problem is, it isn't triggering. (it does trigger on the creation of a user)

I have set all triggers within Cognito to trigger my custom lambda, so I am kind of running out of options? Not sure where to set the forgotPassword trigger instead of Cognito just sending me a verification code.

The front end trigger looks like this:

```
cognitoUser.forgotPassword({
  onSuccess: (data) => { console.log('succes', data); },
  onFailure: (data) => { console.log('failure', data); },
  inputVerificationCode: (data) => { console.log('verification', data); },
});
```

Which uses the amazon-cognito-identity-js library, I tried the same with the Auth lib from Amplify but it gave me the same results.

Answer (score 2):

Wow, I must have overlooked it but my Lambda was checking the source with:

```
  if (event.triggerSource === 'CustomMessage_SignUp') {
```

So, ofcourse it didnt work.. sorry for the time wasted!

Comment: You can use the `CustomMessage_ForgotPassword`, source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-custom-message.html